# How to make a pulse sensor Waterproof ? Or is there any waterproof pulse sensor?

Tags: arduino

Hi there this might sound stupid but please help me . Does anyone know how to make a pulse sensor a waterproof and water resistant one ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to heartrate sensors like those on pulsesensor.org, the simple answer is no.

There are two issues here. The first is whether the circuit could be fully waterproofed - the answer to this is yes. The second is harder, however - which is whether the sensor you refer to would be effective under water.

These sensors use a green light to detect changes in bloodflow, and they work poorly underwater even in commercial sensors. They are very sensitive to being jostled by water, and lose accuracy when there is water between the sensor and the skin.

There's a useful in-depth discussion of this here:

https://www.yourswimlog.com/best-waterproof-heart-rate-monitors-for-swimming/

If you need to measure heartrate underwater, you might have better luck with a chest strap sensor. These work by sensing elongation of a strap wrapped around the chest, and calculate heartrate based on those changes. Commercial versions are readily available and work well.

If all you're worried about is waterproofing the circuit for shallow water, this can be accomplished pretty easily. All elements would need to be encased in fully waterproof material. You could simply slip the whole thing in a waterproof baggie (google 'dry sleeve' or 'acquapac), or if you're up to it, build a silicon mold to encase the project.

Comment: " _... sensing elongation of a strap wrapped around the chest ..._" No, it measures the electrical activity of your heart thru electrical contacts touching your skin. The strap is there to keep the sensor in place.